# Using Bluetooth and Python to change volume of android phone

Tags: python, android, bluetooth

Is there a way to change the master audio volume of android phone through a paired device using a python script?

Something along the lines of this:

```
pairedDevice.volume.set(1.0)
```

I thought of perhaps in someway running `amixer` on the phone through a program which pairs using Bluetooth or maybe somehow access the sound through bluetooth but I could not figure out how that could work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bluetooth devices have profiles or services that they support which tell the connecting device what capabilities are available. Officially adopted ones offer interactivity between two devices if they both support they same service. Here is a list of currently support profiles and services:

https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/profiles-overview/

https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/services/

I am not aware of a standard service that controls the master volume on an android phone. Typically, it would be a Bluetooth speaker can change the volume in the media player on the phone using the A/V Remote Control Profile if it is supported.

It is possible to create custom services but this involves writing code on both ends of the Bluetooth link.

It is not clear from your question what device the Python code will be running on. The support for Python to control Bluetooth will vary greatly depending on the hardware and operating system of that device.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I will ok into the links you have provided. My idea is one Device to be a Raspberry Pi and the other is phone and change the volume of the phone through the Raspberry Pi.